# Excel convert table from horizontal to vertical

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Need to have regular horizontal table to rearrange into vertical as per example.

Used formula inside **E1** `=A1` and inside **E3** `=A2` however when i auto fill down **E5** gets populated with formula `=A5` when needs to be `=A3`.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use INDEX:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$B$5,INT((ROW($ZZ1)-1)/2)+1,MOD(ROW($ZZ1)-1,2)+1)
```

Put that in E1 and copy down till you get errors.

[image]

Comment: Nice however you need to fix INDEX($A$1:$B$5...

Could you explain little bit how it works, e.g. what is $ZZ1

Comment: Yes, I saw that later.  the `$ZZ1` is just a row indicator so our counter always starts at 1 no matter in which row it is placed.

Comment: One more question if i may, how can i do same thing backwards from vertical table to horizontal?

Comment: @RomanToasov that is a new question and new questions get new posts.  That is how this forum is set up.